# C# Send email using Mandrill template 'foreach loop'

Tags: c#, templates, mandrill

I am using mandrill template to send email in my web application . I have a "foreach loop" for  my list of items where I want to auto generate template for the number of items.

how can I add foreach logic in my template and in c# for my back end code?

Assume I have two lists and I want to include all the list of items in my for each loop.

```
var itemList = new List<string>();
var itemList1 = new List<int>();
```

how can i create a loop for this scenario ?

```
foreach (var each in itemList){}
```

Comment: Create a common interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Tuple instead of using two lists separately.

this is what your C# logic for sending emails using template 
//C#

```
var itemContainerTuple = new List<Tuple<string, int?>>();
var mandrill = new MandrillApi(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MandrillApiKey"]);
var emailMessage = new EmailMessage
 {
    FromEmail = "youremail",
    To = new List<EmailAddress> { new EmailAddress { Email = "senderEmail" } },
    Subject = "your subject",
    FromName = "Yourname",
    MergeLanguage = "handlebars",
    Merge = true,
 };

    emailMessage .AddGlobalVariable("ItemContainer", itemContainerTuple);
    await mandrill.SendMessageTemplate(new SendMessageTemplateRequest(emailMessage , "YourTemplateName"));
```

In your Mandrill template You can try like that -

```
//Template
// for each row from tuple string would be red and int would be black. 

{{#each ItemContainer}}   
  <li>
   <span style="color:red"><strong>{{Item1}}</strong></span>         
  </li>

  <li>
   <span style="color:black"><strong>{{Item2}}</strong></span>         
  </li>
{{/each}}
```